# Zend_Auth replacement?

Tags: zend-auth, zend-framework2

Zend_Auth provides an API for authentication and includes concrete authentication adapters for common use case scenarios.

I started working with Zend Framework 2.0 beta1 and I noticed that it doesn't not include the Zend_Auth Module that was provided with Zend Framework 1. any ideas what replaces it?
or maybe it was just removed completely and I need to implement something of my own?

Comment: Questions about frameworks in early beta stages are too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First (just to be clear): everything under library is called a *component* and not a *module*. Also, ZF2 is extremely beta so expect things will change often and no backwards compatibility is guaranteed.

Then, the `Zend_Auth` component has been renamed to `Zend\Authentication`. The first change is the underscore separation to namespaces, the second change is the renaming of Auth to Authentication. As far as I know, the features from `Zend_Auth` are all ported over to `Zend\Authentication`, the new component is also on [GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Authentication).